# Since upgrade from OpenSuse 42.1 to 42.2, raid5 resync upon every reboot

Tags: opensuse, raid

The subject line says it all!  Since the upgrade, the machine is practically unresponsive (KDE login takes 10+ minutes, no exaggeration, to get from the login screen to the desktop) for at least an hour after every bootup.  Remote login confirms "md126_raid5" and "md126_resync" processes using a large chunk of CPU.  (/dev/md126 is the hardware RAID.)

The first time it did this, I figured there must have been a file system update between 42.1 and 42.2, and that this would be a one-time update.  I could tolerate that.  But *every* *single* *boot*?!

Any suggestions (short of reinstalling from scratch) are welcome.

Comment: Software RAID. `/dev/md*` is Linux software RAID (mdraid). Normally this means the array isn't getting shut down cleanly—possibly there is a bug somewhere causing this. You could add write-intent bitmaps to help (will make the rebuild take seconds instead of hours) with `mdadm -G /dev/md126 -b internal`).

Comment: 1) Intel RST (12.5.0.1858) is technically a sort of hybrid, but I call it a hardware RAID because it isn't implemented by the OS from three independent volumes.  The RAID is established before GrUB even loads.

2) This never happened prior to the upgrade from 42.1, and now it happens every time.  Doesn't appear to have anything to do with shutdown.  I suspect a change in the interaction with RST, but I wouldn't know where to begin to look.

Comment: @Dan I'm trying to chase this down on my Gentoo system.  Did you ever get it to behave itself?